# Keep together in reporting Service 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

In reporting services 2008. I have a report where I have not speciified keep together and my report page breaks when the next group is to large to fit on the page.
Also In another report I have a group that expands over 5 pages, and I can't seem to get a group headding to print on multiple pages of the report. In am

Comment: Please restructure question to provide more information. What are you trying to achieve? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The keep togheter is a known bug in SSRS, should sopposedly be fixed in SSRS 2008 R2, but to me it seems to be just as bad.
[See Microsoft Connect page](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/428595/keep-together-property-not-working-in-ssrs-2008)